# Replace abitrary HTML (subtree) within HTML document with other HTML (subtree) with BS4 or regex

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a function along the following lines:

```py
import bs4

def replace(html: str, selector: str, old: str, new: str) -> str:
    
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html) # likely complete HTML document
    old_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(old) # can contain HTML tags etc
    new_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(new) # can contain HTML tags etc
    
    for selected in soup.select(selector):
        
        ### pseudo-code start
        for match in selected.find_everything(old_soup):
            match.replace_with(new_soup)
        ### pseudo-code end
    
    return str(soup)
```

I want to be able to replace an arbitrary HTML subtree below a CSS selector within a full HTML document with another arbitrary HTML subtree. `selector`, `old` and `new` are read as strings from a configuration file.

My document could look as follows:

```py
before = r"""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>No target here</head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is the target!</h1>
    <p class="target">
        Yet another <b>target</b>.
    </p>
    <p>
        <!-- Comment -->
        Foo target Bar
    </p>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

This is supposed to work:

```py
after = replace(
    html = before,
    selector = 'body', # from config text file
    old = 'target', # from config text file
    new = '<span class="special">target</span>', # from config text file
)

assert after == r"""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>No target here</head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is the <span class="special">target</span>!</h1>
    <p class="target">
        Yet another <b><span class="special">target</span></b>.
    </p>
    <p>
        <!-- Comment -->
        Foo <span class="special">target</span> Bar
    </p>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

A plain `str.replace` does not work because the "target" can appear literally everywhere ... I have briefly considered to do this with a regular expression. I have to admit that I did not succeed, but I'd be happy to see this working. Currently, I think my best chance is to use beautifulsoup.

I understand how to swap a specific tag. I can also replace specific text etc. However, I am really failing to replace an "arbitrary HTML subtree", as in I want to replace some HTML with some other HTML in a sane manner. In this context, I want to treat `old` and `new` really as HTML, so if `old` is simply a "word" that does also appear for instance in a class name, I really only want to replace it if it is content in the document, but not if it is a class name as shown above.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution below works in three parts:

1. All matches of `selector` from `html` are discovered.
2. Then, each match (as a `soup` object) is recursively traversed and every child is matched against `old`.
3. If the child object is equivalent to `old`, then it is extracted and `new` is inserted into the original match at the same index as the child object.

---

```py
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
def replace(html:str, selector:str, old:str, new:str) -> str:
    def update_html(d:soup, old:soup) -> None:
        i = 0
        while (c:=getattr(d, 'contents', [])[i:]):
            if isinstance((a:=c[0]), bs4.element.NavigableString) and str(old) in str(a):
                a.extract()
                for j, k in enumerate((l:=str(a).split(str(old)))):
                    i += 1
                    d.insert(i, soup(k, 'html.parser'))
                    if j + 1 != len(l):
                        i += 1
                        d.insert(i, soup(new, 'html.parser'))
            elif a == old:
                a.extract()
                d.insert(i, soup(new, 'html.parser'))
                i += 1
            else:
                update_html(a, old)
            i += 1
    source, o = [soup(j, 'html.parser') for j in [html, old]]
    for i in source.select(selector):
        update_html(i, o.contents[0])
    return str(source)

after = replace(
    html = before,
    selector = 'body', # from config text file
    old = 'target', # from config text file
    new = '<span class="special">target</span>', # from config text file
)
print(after)
```

Output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>No target here</title></head>

<body>
<h1>This is the <span class="special">target</span>!</h1>
<p class="target">
        Yet another <b><span class="special">target</span></b>.
    </p>
<p>
<!-- Comment -->
        Foo <span class="special">target</span> Bar
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to understand your solution, but first: It actually misses one of the replacement targets in the second paragraph, i.e. "Foo *target* Bar". Any idea what goes wrong here?

Comment: Ok, it's also missing the word "target" in the headline. I guess it only replaces elements which are directly and exclusively wrapped in tags - the `<b>`-tags in the above example.

Comment: @s-m-e Apologies for the late response, please see my recent edit.